# Integration tests with spring-security and ldap

Tags: spring-security, integration-testing, spring-ldap

[Spring embedded ldap server in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544550/spring-embedded-ldap-server-in-unit-tests) is similar, however no answer was given that suites me.

I can run my integration tests with spring and the embedded ldap server of spring-security without any problems.
However, I haven't find a way yet to clear the embedded ldap server and load the ldif again to provide a common test environment.

LdapTestUtils of spring-ldap provides a cleanAndSetup() method. However, this does not work with the suggested version (1.5.5) of apache-ds, as LdifFileLoader now requires a *CoreSession* instead of the *DirContext* provided by LdapTestUtils. This causes a

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.apache.directory.server.protocol.shared.store.LdifFileLoader.<init>(Ljavax/naming/directory/DirContext;Ljava/lang/String;)
```

I only want a method that clear the embedded ldap server and fills it with the ldif file again (as done on startup).
Does anybody have an idea regarding this?

Version: spring 3.1, spring-ldap 1.3, spring-security 3.1, apache-ds 1.5.5

**Solution (Thanks to Luke Taylor):**

```
@Inject
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Before
public void reloadLdapDirectory() throws NamingException, IOException{
    ApacheDSContainer apacheDSContainer = (ApacheDSContainer) applicationContext.getBean(BeanIds.EMBEDDED_APACHE_DS);
    LdapTestUtils.clearSubContexts(contextSource, DistinguishedName.EMPTY_PATH);

    ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("ldap.ldif");

    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("spring_ldap_test", ".ldif");
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = classPathResource.getInputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, new FileOutputStream(tempFile));
        LdifFileLoader fileLoader = new LdifFileLoader(apacheDSContainer.getService().getAdminSession(), tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
        fileLoader.execute();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            tempFile.delete();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // Ignore this
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring embedded ldap server in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544550/spring-embedded-ldap-server-in-unit-tests)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not take a look at Spring Security's [LDAP integration tests](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/tree/master/ldap/src/integration-test/java/org/springframework/security/ldap) and use those as a guide?

At the moment, these just [use an LDAP template](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/ldap/src/integration-test/java/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/LdapUserDetailsManagerTests.java#L89) to clear out data that each test has created if necessary (for speed), but there is also a commented-out [Junit `@After` method](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/ldap/src/integration-test/java/org/springframework/security/ldap/ApacheDSServerIntegrationTests.java) which does reload an LDIF file. The `CoreSession` is obtained by calling `getAdminSession()` on the server instance (a `DefaultDirectoryService`).

If you really have to run the tests using an XML application context, using the `<ldap-server />` element, you can use:

```
getBeanByName(BeanIds.EMBEDDED_APACHE_DS).getService()
```

to get access to the `DefaultDirectoryService` instance.

Comment: Hi Luke, first of all: great work with Spring Security! I did take a look at the LDAP integration tests, but they where not helpful to me. I don't start the LDAP server myself, it gets started through <security:ldap-server.../>, so I cannot call getAdminSession() as I don't have a reference to the LDAP server.