# Integration testing with ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, ldap, integration-testing

Last time I've added to our project one more authentication provider in order to authenticate user through windows active directory server:

```
<security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager" erase-credentials="true">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" />
        <security:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider1"/>
        <security:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider2"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>

     <bean id="customLdapUserDetailsMapper" class="security.authentication.customLdapUserDetailsMapper">
     </bean>

     <bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
       <constructor-arg value="my.domain"/>
       <constructor-arg value="ldap://my.custom.host:389" />
       <property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
       <property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
       <property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="customLdapUserDetailsMapper" />
     </bean>
```

Alsmost work fine except existing integration tests that work with authentication flow. Namely each test tried to connect to server when **ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.bindAsUser** then failed because **my.custom.host** is unavaible for this type of test.

I've started googling in order to find some mock for this type of test, but unfortunatly I found only this post [Integration tests with spring-security and ldap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396708/integration-tests-with-spring-security-and-ldap) where **Luke Taylor** recommended use existing integration tests as a guide. I've took a look into it but it doesn't contain any tests for this type of provider.

I'm new in such stuff and would be good to know the following things:

1. Will be it correct to reuse in any manner this approach with `new ApacheDSContainer("dc=springframework,dc=org", "classpath:test-server.ldif");` that was mentioned in LDAP integration test(**I am not sure wheter it suites to me because I didn't create ldap ebbedded ldap server in my application context and didn't specify any .ldif files in mentioned configuration as well**).
2. In which way the following provider can be mocked in proper way?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you just have to provide another configuration which will be loaded for Testing purposes. There you can define a different Authentication Provider, which for example just can authenticate everyone.... Or just simply deactivate Authentication at all.

Since you don't want to test the functionallity provided by spring.